# Missing product option settings issue since WooCommerce 4.4 update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, settings, product

since I have updated WooCommerce 4.4.0 I don't find some product option settings when Creating a new Product or Edit a Product.

To be exact the three Options in the Header:

- Select for Simple, Variable, etc.
- Checkboxes for Virtual and Downloadable

[image: Image how it should look like]

Can someone explain or help me?